# Does calling Python Scikit classifier `.fit` method repeatedly effect anything?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I'm using scikit SVM and I'd like to test an SVM with both the `sample_weights` customized and passed to the classifier and again with the usual implementation where `sample_weights` is the default value of `1` for each sample. (`sample_weight` allows the user to give some samples greater influence than others.) So the workflow is standard-- fit each model to a training subset, test each model on a heldout development set to see if I should use the weights or not. My code is this:

```
clf = svm.SVC( kernel = 'rbf', gamma = .001) ## initialize the model- i only do this once!

clf.fit(X_train, y_train) ## fit the model/do the optimization
accuracy[name + "_no_weights"] = clf.score(X_test, y_test) ## store results

clf.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight = sample_weight_test) ## fit the model/do the optimization w/ different regularization
accuracy[name + "_w_weights"] = clf.score(X_test, y_test) ## store results
```

Notice if I were to test which kernel to use I would have to re-initialize the classifier by redefining `clf`. The point is, above I'm training the same classifier in both cases but I don't re-initialize the classifier. So it could be that on the second time I call `.fit` its parameters are already initialized (not randomly, but from previously training). This would mean the results after the second `.fit` method could have an unfair advantage-- their starting point for the optimization was very close to a good decision boundary.

Anybody know how this works or have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply does not matter for SVM, as it always converges to global minima. It does not "start around good solution", SVM is not a neural network - it does not need a good initialization. In other words - you can call fit how many times you want and you do not have to reinitialize the classifier. In case of sklearn it is even more obvious, as its .fit method does not even pass a current lagrange multipliers, it simply calls external, low-level implementation of SVM solver.

Comment: Ahh.. the quadratic optimization problem has unique, global min?! is that proof of your statement? Also, great answer. You said it's a moot point b/c we're always in the best case scenario.

Comment: @travelingbones The solution of the svm-problem is not necessarily unique but it does not matter here. The fact, that it's a convex optimization problem results in many algorithms which approximate the global minimum. But that's only true for some algorithms (like off-the-shelf QP-solvers, Coordinate-descent, SMO, ...). The currently popular SGD-based methods (often used for huge data) can fail depending on some meta-parameters (most simple: not enough iterations/epochs and learning-rate).

Comment: @travelingbones This kind of proof you can find in any book for numerical analysis. Convex functions have unique (in terms of value) minimum (and strictly convex a unique in terms of coordinates as well). Contrary to what sascha suggests - this applies to svm problem as well - it has a unique solution. However, due to numerical approximations and lack of precision - practical implementations do not converge to actual global solution but simply "close enough" (it's worth noting that this is true for any kind of iterative optimization though).

Comment: @lejlot: thanks for the confirmations. Was aware of the math of convex functions. Wanted to make sure that was the reason here.